# Hibernate getting fields from other tables

Tags: hibernate

I need to get the fields for an entity from other tables linked together without creating additional entities.

```java
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "point_of_rentals")
    public class PointOfRental {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
        @NonNull
        private String name;
        @NonNull
        ??????
        private String country;
        @NonNull
        ??????
        private String city;
        @NonNull
        private String address;
        @NonNull
        private Boolean available;
```

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: Could you please clarify why do you need it? For `city` column you can try to use `@SecondaryTable` , but it will not work for `country`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@Formula` with a subquery to achieve this, but I wouldn't recommend this. It seems to me that what you want here is a DTO projection.